# Plugin or theme?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, themes

I have a wordpress site where people can ask to register and publish their product, I have make a PHP page to list all the product from a table in the database and some other page to insert/modify/delete their own product.
But in the way I have made, if the theme get an update I must copy again all the file.
I would like to make a plugin that can permit to the owner of the product to insert/modify/delete their product from the backoffice (and they can make only that there) and list the product in the frontoffice.
It's a good idea? Since I'm quite new in PHP, from where it's good to start?

Thanks

Comment: Have you considerd making a child theme? That way you can make changes and not loose them when the parent theme gets an update: check out https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/